# Excel count occurrences of parenthesis

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have a data issue where the data now has a name and without a space right away it has a parenthesis,
example : Robert(A1C)

We also have some mixed data where some names are OK with a space , example  :
Evans (B2C)

And the 3rd scenario is that we have multiple brackets : example : Mark (AC1 (B4C))

We are trying to figure out if the data has a space or not and if the data has multiple brackets then ignore those in that analysis and come up with an excel that has a column as such :

```
Robert(A1C) <- KO
Evans (B2C) <- OK
Mark (AC1 (B4C)) <- anything with multiple opening parenthesis should be ignored
```

Expected Output

| Data | IsSpaceMissing |
| --- | --- |
| Robert(A1C) | true |
| Evans (B2C) | false |
| Mark (AC1 (B4C)) | false |

For now I tried doing the count of parenthesis using : =FIND("(",A1) but that's just one piece and wasn't able to figure out how to get the space and without space.

Comment: So find(“ (“,1) and then with an if() check other options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A1,"*(*(*")=0,ISERROR(FIND(" (",A1)))
```

- `COUNTIF(A1,"*(*(*")=0` - Will assure there are no 2+ opening paranthesis and;
- `ISERROR(FIND(" (",A1))` - Will check that there is no space in front op the opening paranthesis.

You can include another check with `FIND()` to see if any opening paranthesis is present if need to.